# Can varchar datatype be a timestamp in Confluent?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using confluent to implement realtime ETL.
My datasource is oracle, every table has a column named ts ,it's data type is varchar, but data in this column is YYYY-MM--DD HH24:MI:SS format.
can I use this column as timestamp in confluent kafka connector ? 
how to config the xxxxx.properties file?

```
mode=timestamp
query= select to_date(a.ts,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') tsinc,a.* from TEST_CORP a
poll.interval.ms=1000 
timestamp.column.name=tsinc
```

Comment: Try looking into single message transform of TimestampConverter

Answer (score 0):

> connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
>   query=select * from NFSN.BD_CORP 
>   mode=timestamp 
>   poll.interval.ms=3000
>   timestamp.column.name=TS topic.prefix=t_ validate.non.null=false

then I get this error:

> [2018-12-25 14:39:59,756] INFO After filtering the tables are: 
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread:175) [2018-12-25
>   14:40:01,383] DEBUG Checking for next block of results from
>   TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='select * from
>   NFSN.BD_CORP', topicPrefix='t_', incrementingColumn='',
>   timestampColumns=[TS]}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:291) [2018-12-25
>   14:40:01,386] DEBUG TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null,
>   query='select * from NFSN.BD_CORP', topicPrefix='t_',
>   incrementingColumn='', timestampColumns=[TS]} prepared SQL query:
>   select * from NFSN.BD_CORP WHERE "TS" > ? AND "TS" < ? ORDER BY "TS"
>   ASC
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier:161)
>   [2018-12-25 14:40:01,386] DEBUG executing query select
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from dual to get current time from database
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.OracleDatabaseDialect:462)
>   [2018-12-25 14:40:01,388] DEBUG Executing prepared statement with
>   timestamp value = 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 end time = 2018-12-25
>   06:40:43.828
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingCriteria:162)
>   [2018-12-25 14:40:01,389] ERROR Failed to run query for table
>   TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='select * from
>   NFSN.BD_CORP', topicPrefix='t_', incrementingColumn='',
>   timestampColumns=[TS]}: {}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:314)
>   java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
>
> ```
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
>     at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:168)
>     at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:88)
>     at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:60)
>     at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:292)
>     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:244)
>     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:220)
>     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
>     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [2018-12-25 14:40:01,390] DEBUG Resetting querier
> ```
>
> TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='select * from
>   NFSN.BD_CORP', topicPrefix='t_', incrementingColumn='',
>   timestampColumns=[TS]}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:332) ^C[2018-12-25
>   14:40:03,826] INFO Kafka Connect stopping
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:65) [2018-12-25
>   14:40:03,827] INFO Stopping REST server
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:223)